# IdentityServer4 Authorization context as transient service

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, identityserver4, .net-5

We have a running IS4 instance for corporate customers (built on top of QuickUI), now the mgmt wants to extend it with another client and they want to have a special layout and page adjustments when the authorization process comes from this client (in essence we need to collect additional info in login form and it has to be branded slightly differently).
Now, adjusting the form and visual appearance is not a problem, but deciding when to show it is proving a challenge. We have our templating and branding in `_Layout` which is used by all the pages, and I somehow need to know inside _layout, if the page load is part of the authentication context and if so, which one.
The way QuickUI did it in `AccountController`, is using IS interaction, which generates `AuthenticationRequest` which contains the client:

```cs
var context = await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
var clientName = context.Client?.ClientName;
```

This fits nicely with AccountController logic and works just fine for authentication purposes, but does little for visual. I do not have the returnUrl inside _Layout (and layout is used by other pages, for registration, etc, so I cannot really cram specific viewmodels into it) and apparently no clean way to determine the context.

a) I could start digging through HttpRequest and parsing request URLs, fishing for returnUrls, but I would first like to see if there is a more streamlined, or even existing solution. 
b) Another option is to have multiple layout files, and expose Client to the ViewModel and switch layouts based on it.
Ideally however, I would like something "clean" and maintainable, a service I could `@inject` into `_Layout.cshtml` and just do `@if (contextService.Client == ...)`

Has someone seen or done something like it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `@if (contextService.Client == ...)` to check what content to show in the page?If so,I think it is ok.

Comment: I would ask to clarify the terms: in IS4 a `Client` is just an app, requested a token and/or user identity. When a user is signed in for the first app, authorization request from the second passes silently except when that is the first request for the app ever and needs a consent. Furthermore when user comes to some internal IS UI page directly there might be no `Client` at all involved.

Comment: So... is the need really to depend on the `Client`, or maybe more a `Tenant` a user belongs to? In the second case you distinguish the tenant from `Interaction`, then assign it as a claim on the user's session in IS4, after that you can rely on that claim in any UI page.

Comment: @d_f, No, I am the authenticator, clients use me as OAuth identity provider. They invoke me using client_id I supplied for them and at that point there is no assigned claim or logged in user. Think of me as Google OAuth in this scenario.

Comment: @Yiyi You, yes. The problem is there is no such service provided, so nothing for me to inject. I am trying to avoid writing a flimsy one by digging through the native request object, I am hoping there is some way to construct that object in a supported and stable way

Answer (score 0):

Until (and if) someone posts a "cleaner" solution (especially the one that does not revolve around `returnUrl` magic string), this is the workaround I implemented. It's dirty, I admit, it pokes on `HttpContext` from a service, which is not really asp.net core way, but at this point, I see no other way to obtain the information I need to construct authorization context:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MyServices
{
    public interface IContextService
    {
        Task<AuthorizationRequest> GetContextAsync();
    }

    public class ContextService : IContextService
    {
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
        private AuthorizationRequest context;

        public ContextService(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {
            this.interaction = interaction;
            this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task<AuthorizationRequest> GetContextAsync() => context ??= await InternalObtainContextAsync();

        private async Task<AuthorizationRequest> InternalObtainContextAsync()
        {
            var query = contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Query;
            if (query == null || query.Count == 0 || !query.ContainsKey("returnUrl")) return new AuthorizationRequest(); // empty context
            return await interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(query["returnUrl"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Register in startup with `services.AddTransient<IContextService, ContextService>();` and then you can inject it into any page and/or layout:

```
@inject IContextService contextService;

@{
    // render only when invoked from authorization context
    var context = await contextService.GetContextAsync();
    if (context.Client != null)
    {
        <div>Hi, I am inside authorization context for client @context.Client.ClientId</div>
    }
}
```